# How to replace/update an old version of Ruby

Tags: ruby

Mavericks 10.9.1

I'm have difficulty updating ruby 1.9.3p194

```
rvm install 2.1.0

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.1.0.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for smf.
SMF Framework support is only intended for RailsInstaller / Tokaido.app, please use Macports / Homebrew integration instead.
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

I've tried Homebrew but this doesn't work either. Doctor reveals a number of issues. Can anyone help?

Comment: What issues are you getting with `brew doctor`? Please append them to your answer. You really need a package manager, otherwise RVM is worthless.

Comment: Make sure you followed these installation instructions for Homebrew first: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/setting-up-os-x-mavericks-and-homebrew/